# Generics and database - a design issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, generics, strong-typing

The situation is that I have a table that models an entity. This entity has a number of properties (each identified by a column in the table). The thing is that in the future I'd need to add new properties or remove some properties. The problem is how to model both the database and the corresponding code (using C#) so that when such an occasion appears it would be very easy to just "have" a new property.

In the beginning there was only one property so I had one column. I defined the corresponding property in the class, with the appropriate type and name, then created stored procedures to read it and update it. Then came the second property, quickly copy-pasted, changed name and type and a bit of SQL and there it was. Obviously this is not a suitable model going forward. By this time some of you might suggest an ORM (EF or another) because this will generate the SQL and code automatically but for now this is not an option for me.

I thought of having only one procedure for reading one property (by property name) and another one to update it (by name and value) then some general procedures for reading a bunch or all properties for an entity in the same statement. This may sound easy in C# if you consider using generics but the database doesn't know generics so it's not possible to have a strong typed solution.

I would like to have a solution that's "as strongly-typed as possible" so I don't need to do a lot of casting and parsing. I would define the available properties in code so you don't go guessing what you have available and use magic strings and the like. Then the process of adding a new property in the system would only mean adding a new column to the table and adding a new property "definition" in code (e.g. in an enum).

Comment: Why can't you use the EF? The geniuses at Microsoft have already figured out and done a lot of work for you in this regard. I'd hate to see you re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why you need to avoid an ORM.  (also, I have no idea what C# generics has to do with any of this)

Comment: I agree but EF is a bit farther down the road with regards to the architecture so I can't use it just yet.

Comment: What does "a bit farther down the road" mean?  Why must you not use it?

Comment: I mentioned generics because I still need some "feel" of strong typing. When you'd call `GetProperty("PropertyName")` it wouldn't be that helpful to always return `Object`.

Comment: Farther might mean weeks or months. As with any big project (that I've seen so far), change is difficult and looked upon with a lot of reserve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do this:

```
MyObj x = new MyObj();
x.SomeProperty = 10;
```

You have a table created for that, but you dont want to keep altering that table when you add

```
x.AnotherProperty = "Some String";
```

You need to normalize the table data like so:

```
-> BaseTable
   RecordId, Col1, Col2, Col3

-> BaseTableProperty
   PropertyId, Name

-> BaseTableValue
   ValueId, RecordId, PropertyId, Value
```

Your class would look like so:

```
 public class MyObj
 {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
      public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
 }
```

When you create your object from your DL, you enumerate the record set. You then write code once that inspect the property as the same name as your configuration (`BaseTableProperty.Name` == `MyObj.<PropertyName>` - and then attempt the type cast to that type as you enumerate the record set.

Then, you simply add another property to your object, another record to the database in `BaseTableProperty`, and then you can store values for that guy in `BaseTableValue`.

Example:

```
 RecordId
 ========
 1

 PropertyId          Name
 ==========          ====
 1                   SomeProperty

 ValueId     RecordId       PropertyId      Value
 =======     ========       ==========      =====
 1           1              1               100
```

You have two result sets, one for basic data, and one joined from the Property and Value tables. As you enumerate each record, you see a Name of `SomeProperty` - does `typeof(MyObj).GetProperty("SomeProperty")` exist? Yes? What it it's data type? int? Ok, then try to convert "100" to `int` by setting the property:

```
 propertyInfo.SetValue(myNewObjInstance, Convert.ChangeType(dbValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

For each property.

Comment: Getting close but I don't really want or need to declare each property in the class. It rarely happens that I need more than one property at one time. Most of the times I have the object ID and need to know just one of the properties. That's why I was going towards having a general `GetProperty(int objectID, string propertyName)` method.

Comment: I will accept this as it's the closest to the solution I'm going to take.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you said you cannot use them, that is what most ORM do. Depending on which one you use (or even create if it's a learning experience), they will greatly vary in complexity and performance. If you prefer a light weight ORM, check [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It makes use of generics as well, so you can check the code, see how it works, and create your own solution if needed.